# Get class method definition from .cpp file using clang CXXMethodDecl

Tags: c++, class, methods, clang, llvm

I want to get class methods' definition location and line numbers.
Lets say I have .h file with single class containing one simple method declaration.
Also I've got .cpp file with method definition.
How am I supposed to obtain definition from .cpp file line numbers of given method?
I tried using `getDefinition()` method on CXXMethodDecl* object, but it returns nullptr.
When theres definition with declaration in .h file of method, simply `getSourceRange()` method works.